# Is Git hiding files on my computer?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've accidentally created two branches for my Git repository: `main` and `master`, which I now need to merge.

However, when using `ls` on the command line while checked into `main` branch, some files on my computer don't show up (files that don't exist in the main branch on GitHub). When I use `git checkout master` the files "reappear".

But they must always be on my hard drive, so why are they hidden from view when checked into this one branch?

Comment: Much of what git does is made possible by having files in the "hidden" directory called `.git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is not "hiding" these files from you, it is just that these files are only on the "main" branch. If you want just one branch with all your files, you can merge these branches by typing `git merge master` while you're checked into main.

If you want to learn more about how git's branches work: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

If you want to learn about the merge command in a lot more detail: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: It might be worth understanding that this is in fact achieved with hidden files in a hidden .git directory

Comment: If you consider all files in a hidden directory to be hidden, then yes, but in the repository I just checked, there are no files in `.git` that are hidden on their own.